# How to access iPhone dialer keypad from trigger.io API

Tags: trigger.io

How do I show dialer keypad in trigger.io app?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing the HTML5 number input should cause the default number keypad to appear on the device:

```
<input name="txtPhone" id="txtPhone" value="" type="number">
```